# How do I import an existing Liferay project into the Liferay Developer Studio

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-ide

I am using Liferay Developer Studio
Version: 2.2.2.201504240205-ga3a, and 
I have an existing Liferay project that
is made up of multiple portlets. I have 
the SDK installed, and I have deployed 
some test portlets (with Maven/Ant). How 
do I create 1 war file that deploys 
the portlets correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your existing project is an SDK project (e.g. utilizes Ant), it's probably contained in an SDK folder. Use "Window/Preferences/Liferay/Installed Plugin SDKs" to make this SDK known to Liferay. Then just use "File/Import/Liferay Projects from Plugins SDK" to import your project.

If it's a maven plugin try if it's "File/Import/Liferay Project from existing source" or just a plain import of a maven project.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I re installed the IDE and followed your advice.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. There's an "accept answer" button next to each answer that you can and should click as well (for whatever answer helped best)

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the plugins(which has many plugins and examples) source code, stick the code in the plugins folder of the source. This will make the parent in the ant task the sdk, then import the project, so your projects folder will be next to other plugins.

```
/Liferays/plugins-src/liferay-plugins-6.2.0-ga1/portlets$ ls -la
total 408
drwxr-xr-x 96 jimmy jimmy 4096 Nov  2 16:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 akismet-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 ams-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 analog-clock-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 bible-gateway-portlet
-rw-r--r--  1 jimmy jimmy  730 Nov  1  2013 build-common-portlet.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jimmy jimmy 8926 Nov  1  2013 build.xml
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 calendar-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 chat-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 chat-video-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 contacts-portlet
-rw-r--r--  1 jimmy jimmy  922 Nov  1  2013 create.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jimmy jimmy  778 Nov  1  2013 create.sh
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 ddl-form-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 events-display-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 flash-portlet
drwxr-xr-x  4 jimmy jimmy 4096 May 23  2014 google-adsense-portlet
```

place the folder that contains the code here.